# Excel table names contain a '$' when pulled from a schema in VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, schema

I have a list box that I'm trying to populate in an application to contain Excel tab names or Access tables. It's created by a simple schema grab:

```
dtSheet = OpenCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
```

It then gets put into a simple list (of String):

```
For Each Row In dtSheet.Rows
    ListOfSheets.Add(Row("TABLE_NAME").ToString())
Next
```

This works fine if I open up an Access database, the names of the tables are listed nicely. However, when I use it for Excel, I get symbols such as $ and quotes "'". I'd like to trim this off to just have the tab names but so far I haven't been able to find anything to help my issue specifically.

My suspicion is that the answer is in the {Nothing...."TABLE"} object. I'm a little light on how filters like this work and I was having issues wrapping my head around it after reading the .NET documentation.

Another idea would be to do some post string alteration trimming but I'd like to see if there was an easier way to get the simple string name that I want from the start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's just how things work with Excel. Excel is a spreadsheet, not a database. When you use ADO.NET to retrieve data from an Excel spreadsheet, you need to prefix sheet names with that "$" symbol. If you don't want to display it in your app, you just have to use string manipulation to remove it. There's nothing in ADO.NET to do it because, as far as it is concerned, they are part of the table names. Those table names are `Strings` like any other, so you trim characters like you would for any other `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion from jmcihinney, I built a slightly better code.

```
dtSheet = OpenCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
dtSheet.Columns.Add("Table_Text", Type.GetType("System.String"))
For i As Integer = dtSheet.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
      If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(dtSheet.Rows(i)("TABLE_NAME"), 1) <> "$" Then
           dtSheet.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
      Else
           dtSheet.Rows(i)("TABLE_Text") = Replace(dtSheet.Rows(i)("TABLE_NAME"), "$", "")
      End If
Next
```

I essentially add a column to the datatable that is built from the list pull. To remove anything that isn't a table (e.g. named ranges, Sheet views) I check the Table_Name column for the suffix of "$". Note I go backwards to keep from messing with any indexing.

Then in the Else statement I put a "Replace" to make the table_text a "$"less version of Table_Name

That way I can then build my listbox like this:

```
Me.lbTableList.DataSource = dtsheet
Me.lbTableList.DisplayMember = "TABLE_Text"
Me.lbTableList.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME"
```

This makes my table look nice regardless if I loaded an Access database or Excel file. This also allows me to just pass the TABLE_NAME to the connection command and not worry whether there is a "$" in the name or not:

```
DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & strTable & "]"
```